# Can not profile a cuda code with nvprof when using CUPTI functions inside

Tags: cuda, metric, nvprof

I'm doing a simple experiment. Everyone may know about *callback_metric* sample code of CUPTI (located in CUPTI folder: `/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/sample/callback_metric`). It contains only a simple code for reading a metric when running a *vectorAdd* kernel. Everything works when I compile and run the code.

But when I run this code under *nvprof* command (`nvprof  ./callback_metric`), I get an error message as:

```
Error: incompatible CUDA driver version
```

both nvprof and other CUPTI-based codes work fine separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The profilers are not intended to be used in this way with applications that make use of CUPTI.

This is documented in the profiler [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#profiler-known-issues):

> Here are a couple of reasons why Visual Profiler may fail to gather metric or event information.
>   More than one tool is trying to access the GPU. To fix this issue please make sure only one tool is using the GPU at any given point. Tools include the CUDA command line profiler, Parallel NSight Analysis Tools and Graphics Tools, and applications that use either CUPTI or PerfKit API (NVPM) to read event values.